# How can i include properties from application.properties file in chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra

**how can i include properties from application.properties file in chef recipe**

I have  a application.properties file. I want to use the properties defined in this file in chef recipe.
How can i use this.

Answer (score 1):

Write some code to read I the file and parse it. Make sure you do this at a point in the code where the file is on disk, usually in a ruby_block resource so it happens at converge time.